# onclick function call is not working in apache cordova(version 6.1.1)

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

i am trying to call the JavaScript function in `onclick` of button. But it is not working.

i am  using some cordova plugins

1. sqlite
2. File
3. File transfer
4. dbcopy
5. File Path

   ```
   <button onclick="testalert()"> test alert </button> <script> function testalert() { alert("alert is working"); } </script>
   ```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="io.cordova.gkslapp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"><intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name"> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> </intent-filter> </activity> </application> <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used jQuery's delegate function with the call with document object.
To make the code readable, we created a js fill which had only delegate function, Something like this.

`$(document).delegate(".cus-name", "click", showLoader);`

Here *showLoader* is a function which is in some other file. The main reason to use delegate function was because we load pages and parts of pages dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

First: all of the JS functionalities in a cordova/phonegap project should be executed after the [`deviceready`](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#deviceready) event

Second: Since you're using jQuery use the [`click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) function instead, it's a better practice

Answer (score 0):

```
**index.html**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <!--
        Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
            https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
        Some notes:
            * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
            * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
            * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
                * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">


    </head>
    <body >



        <div id="target">
            Click here
        </div>




        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>



**index.js**




$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Button Clicked" );
});


Try this .
```

Comment: Please read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303605/4284627) about code-only answers